# Unable to perform conditional redirect from a class based view Django

Tags: django, redirect

I am trying to redirect a user who has already registered to a different view. here is the code for the views.py

However when qs.exists() = true I get an error
'The view Lpage.views.homeview didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.'

I am a beginner have read the documentation but unable to find where i am going worng.
Thanks

```
    from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
    from django.views import View
    from Lpage.forms import SubscriberEntryForm
    from Lpage.models import Subscriber


    class homeview(View):

       def get(self,request):
          msg = request.session.get('msg', False)
          if(msg):
             del(request.session['msg'])
          return render(request,'Lpage/index.html')

      def post(self, request):
          form = SubscriberEntryForm(request.POST or None)
          if form.is_valid():
              obj = form.save(commit=False)
              qs = Subscriber.objects.filter(email__iexact=obj.email)
              if qs.exists():                
                  return redirect('messageview')
              else:
                  obj.save()
                  request.session['msg'] = "msg"
                  return redirect(request.path)


     def messageview(request):
        return render(request,'Lpage/messages.html',{})
```

Here is the error message

ValueError at /
The view Lpage.views.homeview didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/
Django Version: 3.2.7
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value:
The view Lpage.views.homeview didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
Exception Location: C:\Users\Ganesamurthi\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py, line 309, in check_response
Python Executable:  C:\Users\Ganesamurthi\anaconda3\python.exe
Python Version: 3.8.5
Python Path:
['D:\dreamdoors\dd',
'C:\Users\Ganesamurthi\anaconda3\python38.zip',
'C:\Users\Ganesamurthi\anaconda3\DLLs',
'C:\Users\Ganesamurthi\anaconda3\lib',
'C:\Users\Ganesamurthi\anaconda3',
'C:\Users\Ganesamurthi\anaconda3\lib\site-packages',
'C:\Users\Ganesamurthi\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32',
'C:\Users\Ganesamurthi\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32\lib',
'C:\Users\Ganesamurthi\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin']
Server time:    Wed, 29 Sep 2021 05:23:43 +0000
Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view
C:\Users\Ganesamurthi\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py, line 47, in inner
response = get_response(request) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\Ganesamurthi\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py, line 188, in _get_response
self.check_response(response, callback) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\Ganesamurthi\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py, line 309, in check_response
raise ValueError( …
▶ Local vars

Comment: Please [edit] your question and share the _full_ error traceback, also fix the indentation of your code.

Answer (score 0):

[redirect](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) expects you to pass a URL but you gave it `messageview`, which is a view class in fact.

So you need to give `redirect` to the URL of `messageview`.

Comment: Giving a URL to redirect did not fix the problem, getting the same error

Comment: Could you edit your question to show  your final `return redirect('messageview')` and your `urls.py` files?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I found the error, it has nothing to do with redirect. The form was failing in validation and hence the subsequent statements where failing and redirect was not happening.

Comment: Usage of `redirect` is not correct, as well. Please consider the suggestion in my answer.

Comment: `redirect` _can_ take a view name though which will try calling `reverse` (It's written in the documentation you yourself linked to), so that is not necessarily incorrect...

Comment: [reverse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse) can takes view and return url path. So, in the end you pass url path to `redirect`. In my answer, I told you `redirect` cannot directly take view as a parameter. You have to pass url to it. This is what revorse does. So, there is no mistake.